Why does the horizontal scrollbar move the labels to the leftside?
I've encountered a problem in my code with CTkScrollableFrame and labels.
I am working on a calculator application using custom tkinter. The calculator is divided into 2 frames - display and buttons. The display contains current and total expression.
The problem is that the scrollbar moved both the expression to the leftside, when originally they were on right. Can you help me to move the labels to the right side?
With scrollbar
I want it to look like this but with scrollabar.
Without scrollbar
from customtkinter import *

    def create_display_frame(self):
        """
        @brief Create the display frame with total and current expression labels
        @param self: Instance of the class
        """

        self.displayFrame = CTkFrame(self, width=400, height=150, fg_color=DARK_GRAY, border_width=5,
                                               border_color=GRAY, corner_radius=0)
        self.displayFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.totalLabel = CTkLabel(self.displayFrame, text=self.totalExpression, anchor="e", padx=15, pady=20,
                                   font=(SMALL, 22), text_color="white")
        self.totalLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.currentLabel = CTkLabel(self.displayFrame, text=self.currentExpression, anchor="e", padx=15, pady=20,
                                     font=(LARGE, 50), text_color="white")
        self.currentLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.displayFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.displayFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.displayFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

I tried to change the anchors of labels, but that didn't work.

You did not use CTkScrollableFrame in your code.  It is better to provide a [mre].

You might want to replace sticky="nsew" by sticky="nsw" when gridding the labels so they are "glued" to the right border.

You might want to replace sticky="nsew" by sticky="nsw", this unfortunately didn't work. The labels are still on the left side.
